# Is it possible to specify a variable as size specifier for a statically allocated integer array?

Tags: c++, compilation, static-array

I'm surprised that this code compiles and works perfectly without throwing any errors!

```
int arraysize = 1000;
int array[arraysize];
for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
{
    array[i] = i+1;
}

for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
{
    cout << array[i];
}
```

Edit: Compiler used: i386-linux-gnueabi-g++ (Linaro GCC 4.5-2012.01) 4.5.4 20120105 (prerelease)

Comment: @KerrekSB, that's why the OP is surprised that the code compiles, I believe?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the size of an array must be a constant. If you were to declare the size variable `const`, then it could be used.

C allows variable-length arrays (sometimes called VLAs), and some C++ compilers provide these as an extension; that would be why your code works.

Usually, `std::vector` is a safer and more portable alternative if you need a dynamically-sized array.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a feature of your compiler (GCC ?) which allows C99 variable-length arrays. In C99, it's valid to define arrays such as

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int array[n];
```

C++ does not, by standard, support variable-length arrays, probably because it has better alternatives, namely `std::vector<>`. Try compiling with `g++ -pedantic-errors file.cpp` and you'll receive

```
error: ISO C++ forbids variable-size array ‘array’
```

It should be noted that variable-length arrays do not support C++ classes, which is another reason not to bother with them in C++, and instead using `std::vector<>`.

Comment: VLAs are really hard to make consistent with the C++ object model. What if there's an exception in a constructor of one of the elements, for example?